# How do I set notification in android application at specific time?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have used following code in `android application` to `set up Notification(Alarm)` using `AlarmManager`.

```
 public void setAlarm() {
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimeAlarm.class);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

          am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
            (40000), pendingIntent);
         }
```

Or should I use following code

```
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

      calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
      calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
      calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 21);

      calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,11);
      calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
      calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
      calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);

      Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
      pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

> I want to set (notification)alarm at this specific time : 11:15AM on 21-March-2015
>
> Can any one help me to set this?

Comment: Why you want to set repeat alarm if `11:15AM on 21-March-2015` comes only once in calendar?

Comment: @Apurva aha not actually repeat alarm I want notification only once please correct me if I'm using wrong code ? want to set notification once only to specific time : 11:15AM on 21-March-2015

Comment: @ashish If seconds are equal to 0 you can also not set them and if the hour is under 12AM you can also not set Calendar.AM_PM (just some optimizations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to use `Calendar` to set your date something like:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15);

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
```

And then in your `setAlarm()` method you need to set the alarm only once. You don't need to repeat it so:

```
public void setAlarm() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimeAlarm.class);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

     am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use alarm manager with service.
2. Service will introduce in manifest file.
3. Please follow below tutorial care fully.

A. http://nnish.com/2014/12/16/scheduled-notifications-in-android-using-alarm-manager/

B. http://androidideasblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/alarmmanager-and-notificationmanager.html

C. https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.AlarmManager
D. http://www.banane.com/2014/05/07/simple-example-of-scheduled-self-clearing-android-notifications/

I hope it will help for you.

Answer (score 1):

Run one thread every second and compare your specified time with current time, and if matches set notification.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm aa");
String dateTimeinSrting = "21-Mar-2015 11:15 am";

try {
    Date dateTime = formatter.parse(dateTimeInString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

float dateTimeInMillis = dateTime.getTime();

handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        Calendar calendar;

        if(Float.compare(dateTimeInMillis, calendar.getTimeInMillis())){
            //Set the notification here
        }

        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```